# Superpatients for Cancer resistance

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, cancer, dna-sequencing, biotechnology

I was reading an article on MIT Technology review about superpatients for low cholesterol that got me thinking whether such patients exist for cancer.

The article is

http://www.technologyreview.com/featuredstory/532421/the-search-for-exceptional-genomes/

I had also previously read an article on naked mole rats and the hyaluronan in the ECM.

http://www.wired.com/2013/06/naked-mole-rat-cancer/

Therefore, I am wondering whether there are any current studies, that is trying to discover the genetic outliers for cancers. Ie, humans that have hyaluronan in their ECM that is almost naked mole rat like. Since I understand that with a genetic pool of 7+ billion there has to be at least one outlier.

Thanks